# Match data in Any Column, and change data over all Other Columns in Same Row

Tags: linux, csv, for-loop, awk, text-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to search a csv file for a value, in this case "---", and change all proceeding columns in the same row to "---".

I have been looking to do this with awk, but I can only figure out how to check for known fields,

i.e.-

```
awk '{if ($(NF-1)=="---")$NF="---"}{print $0}' file
```

I need to find a way to use a for loop, I think(that's why I'm asking) to:

1) Search all the fields for a value

2) Find the value in a field, and change all proceeding fields of the same record to a specific value (i.e.- "---" )

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.  And I apologize if my wording doesn't convey all the different trial and error attempts I have made at this, I would like to know what does work instead of showing everybody what does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.csv
a,b,---,d,e
1,---,3,4,5
```

To look for `---` and change all preceding columns in the same row to `---`:

```
$ awk -F, '{f=0; for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) {$i=(f?"---":$i); f=($i=="---")}} 1' OFS=, file.csv
---,---,---,d,e
---,---,3,4,5
```

Alternatively, to  look for `---` and change all subsequent (succeeding) columns in the same row to `---`:

```
$ awk -F, '{f=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {$i=(f?"---":$i); f=($i=="---")}} 1' OFS=, file.csv
a,b,---,---,---
1,---,---,---,---
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for.  An Awk one liner that can Patten match and change the format of data preceding or proceeding.  Thank you.